# How to format time as a string in "2nd Jan 2006" time format using time package

Tags: string, date, go, time, format

I want the date in the format "31st Dec 2020" in Go.

I'm using the following code lines to get the time as in the above mentioned format.

```
time := 2020-12-31
wantedFormat := time.Format("2nd Jan 2006")
```

But when I print wantedFormat it give the value as 31nd Dec 2020. I want it as 31st. How can I get the answer I'm expecting?

Comment: Are you trying to fix this behaviour for just this particular date? or do you want it to work for any other date value? For instance do you want to show, `30th Dec 2020`, or just want it to work for `2020-12-31`? If it's the first one, you can just change your format string to `2st Jan 2006`. The `st` is not part of any standard format of go, so it will just show up as-is in the formatted time.

Comment: you should support internationalization also?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Lucas that you should take a look into the time package and available formats.

I haven't really received a reply to my earlier clarification, but I think I can take a stab at an answer, assuming you want the code to do the smartest thing (which is handle all kinds of different dates).

You can extract the date value from your time string and then pass it to a switch to choose an appropriate suffix, `st`, `nd`, `rd` or `th`.

```
myTime := "2020-12-10"

extractedDateFromMyTime := myTime[len(myTime) - 2 : len(myTime)]

dateInt, _ := strconv.Atoi(extractedDateFromMyTime)

suffix := ""
  
if Abs(dateInt) >= 10 && Abs(dateInt) <= 19 {
  suffix = "th"
} else {
  switch Abs(dateInt) % 10 {
    case 1:
      suffix = "st"
    case 2:
      suffix = "nd"
    case 3:
      suffix = "rd"
    default:
      suffix = "th" 
  }
}

myFormat := "2" + suffix + " Jan 2006"

t, _ := time.Parse(layoutISO, myTime)
```

This code above deals with the case of `2020-12-01` and `2020-12-1` (without the zero) by taking the absolute value after extracting the date (two characters from the end). So it assumes this format will be maintained and won't be something like `2020 Dec 1`. I haven't shown the absolute function, but i think that would be easy for you to implement (also see my shared golang playground)

Here's a sample output:

```
myTime: 2020-12-10
Extracted Date from myTime: 10
10th Dec 2020


myTime: 2020-12-31
Extracted Date from myTime: 31
31st Dec 2020
```

And finally, here's the go playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/7cBg55Vp0mm

Answer (score 1):

The [`time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/) package cannot ordinalize numbers.

So what you should do is use the `time` package to only format the month and year parts, and handle the day ordinalization yourself (and concatenate the results).

Ordinalization isn't difficult:

```
func Ordinalize(x int) string {
    if x >= 10 && x < 19 {
        return fmt.Sprint(x, "th")
    }

    switch x % 10 { // the last digit
    case 1:
        return fmt.Sprint(x, "st")
    case 2:
        return fmt.Sprint(x, "nd")
    case 3:
        return fmt.Sprint(x, "rd")
    }

    return fmt.Sprint(x, "th")
}
```

Using this helper, your wished format is assembled like this:

```
s := Ordinalize(t.Day()) + t.Format(" Jan 2006")
```

Testing it with all possible days:

```
for day := 1; day <= 31; day++ {
    t := time.Date(2020, time.December, day, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    s := Ordinalize(t.Day()) + t.Format(" Jan 2006")
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qj0g2GfOXm3)):

```
1st Dec 2020
2nd Dec 2020
3rd Dec 2020
4th Dec 2020
5th Dec 2020
6th Dec 2020
7th Dec 2020
8th Dec 2020
9th Dec 2020
10th Dec 2020
11th Dec 2020
12th Dec 2020
13th Dec 2020
14th Dec 2020
15th Dec 2020
16th Dec 2020
17th Dec 2020
18th Dec 2020
19th Dec 2020
20th Dec 2020
21st Dec 2020
22nd Dec 2020
23rd Dec 2020
24th Dec 2020
25th Dec 2020
26th Dec 2020
27th Dec 2020
28th Dec 2020
29th Dec 2020
30th Dec 2020
31st Dec 2020
```

Answer (score 0):

As m_vemuri said, `st` is not part of any standard format of go. Please check this [example](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#example_Time_Format) from the go official documentation.

The [whole time package documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)

This is an example of how you should handle it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t, err := time.Parse(time.UnixDate, "Wed Feb 25 11:06:39 PST 2015")
    if err != nil { // Always check errors even if they should not happen.
        panic(err)
    }

    // time.Time's Stringer method is useful without any format.
    fmt.Println("default format:", t)

    // Predefined constants in the package implement common layouts.
    fmt.Println("Unix format:", t.Format(time.UnixDate))

    // The time zone attached to the time value affects its output.
    fmt.Println("Same, in UTC:", t.UTC().Format(time.UnixDate))
}
```

And here are the available [formats](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants):

```
const (
    ANSIC       = "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 2006"
    UnixDate    = "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 MST 2006"
    RubyDate    = "Mon Jan 02 15:04:05 -0700 2006"
    RFC822      = "02 Jan 06 15:04 MST"
    RFC822Z     = "02 Jan 06 15:04 -0700" // RFC822 with numeric zone
    RFC850      = "Monday, 02-Jan-06 15:04:05 MST"
    RFC1123     = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 MST"
    RFC1123Z    = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700" // RFC1123 with numeric zone
    RFC3339     = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
    RFC3339Nano = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00"
    Kitchen     = "3:04PM"
    // Handy time stamps.
    Stamp      = "Jan _2 15:04:05"
    StampMilli = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000"
    StampMicro = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000000"
    StampNano  = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000000000"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the [goment library](https://github.com/nleeper/goment) for because it support i18n also, as example:

```
func main() {
    g, err := goment.New(time.Date(2015, 11, 10, 5, 30, 0, 0, time.UTC))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(g.Format("DD-MM-YYYY"))
    fmt.Println(g.Format("Do"))
    g.SetLocale("es")
    fmt.Println(g.Format("Do"))

}
```

will output:

```
10-11-2015
10th
10º
```

[try also on playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QCMs1ZXWOK-)

Answer (score 0):

you can try go-carbon，a simple，semantic and developer-fridendly golang package for datetime

```golang
carbon.Parse("2020-12-31").Format("jS M Y") // 31st Dec 2020
```

https://github.com/golang-module/carbon